# Rspec 3 with devise: uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I am trying to set up rails_rspec with devise.

When I run: *rspec* all the tests run fine.

When I try with *bundle exec rspec* I get: config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)

The error happens in the initializer file, I have devise in my gemfile. I'm using rails 4 with  Devise version 3.4.1 and Rspec version 3.2.0.

Here's the full trace:

```
/Users/glesauteur/Marc/gigmarket/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /Users/glesauteur/Marc/gigmarket/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/glesauteur/Marc/gigmarket/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
from /Users/glesauteur/Marc/gigmarket/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/glesauteur/Marc/gigmarket/spec/models/client_spec.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/glesauteur/Marc/gigmarket/spec/models/client_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /Users/glesauteur/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: does the rails server run normally? when running `bin/rails s`

Comment: Make sure you added `devise` for all environments?

Comment: Have you added `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller` (source : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise ) ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yes rails s runs normally.

Comment: @PramodShinde devise is for all environments yes!

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm yes, I added the line in rails_helper.rb